# Assigning an array of values in Adobe DTM to a list var

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

I have a list of values which I have gathered from some HTML elements in a page with some javascript. I have then stored these within an array called 'a'. This is all processed as a data element.

a = 123, 456, 789, 102

What I would like to achieve is to find all of the values on a given page then record an instance against each value as an instance, essentially I am counting the number of times an item appears in search results by ID. The part I am stuck on, is how I would assign these values to a list var and record these as an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling s.events, s.linkTrackVars and s.linkTrackEvents I was able to record the data within a list variable in omniture. I have provided the code I used below:

```
if (location.href.indexOf('example.com') != '-1') {
    var a = "";

    $('div.info').each(function() {
          if(a.length<1){
            a =($(this).attr('id'))
          }else{
             a = a + "," + ($(this).attr('id'))
          }
        })
        if (a.length > 1)
            s.list1 = a;
                s.events="event100";
                s.linkTrackVars="list1,events";
                s.linkTrackEvents="event100";
                s.tl(true, 'o', 'ID count');
    }
```